# Compilation failed for data model at path

Tags: ios, core-data, compiler-errors

I'm trying to release an app to the app store tonight.  I've been developing the  Xcode 6 - Beta 2 for the past few months (Objective-C only) and didn't know you were not allowed to submit via Xcode Beta.  So, I opened the project in plain Xcode and upon an attempt to re-archive the project received the following error:

`Compilation failed for data model at path '/Users/ME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectDataFolder/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Project.app/Model.momd/Model.mom'`

I tried deleting the derived data, cleaning the build folder, etc etc the standard stuff. I also tried cleaning the archives folder and the simulator apps folder.  Neither worked.  However, reopening the app in Xcode Beta worked on the first try. Back to Xcode, same error occurred.

Any help would be greatly appreciaed.

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your issue? If so please mark the answer :)

Comment: I've tried all the answers and haven't been able to solve a similar problem where I'm getting that error.

Answer (score 94):

I had this problem after creating a new CoreData model version and immediately deleting it.  The said version didn't appear in Xcode's Project Navigator but was causing the compilation error. I used the "Show in Finder" at one of the model versions and found the .mom file of the deleted model version. Manual deletion solved it for me.

Answer (score 18):

I have faced the same issue (Xcode version - 6.1.1). For me the following 2 steps helped:

- I deleted extra model versions by using the "Show in Finder" option for .xcdatamodel file
- I removed a reference to an .xcdatamodel file and added it again

Comment: First, I don't have any "extra" models.  How do you remove the reference and add it back?

Comment: Actually, I had a similar issue, I was receiving this error, so I cleaned the build with command+shift+k, and also the folder with command+option+shift+k, and recompiled the whole project and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error, in my instance this was caused by us accidentally having the xcdatamodelid file referenced twice in `Targets->Build Phases->Compile sources` 
Simply deleting one of the duplicate entries fixed it.

This may not have been what caused your issue, but it had me stumped for a couple of days so worth checking if anyone else gets stuck on the same problem again.

Comment: In my instance the xcdatamodel was referenced twice but it showed up with no extension and in red the second time in the Compile Sources list. This was due to a bad merge in git of the project.pbxproj file. Deleting the duplicate fixed the issue. Another strange issue was that first we tried deleting DerivedData to resolve the issue and it fixed the error at first, but then the error came back a bit later.

Answer (score 4):

This issue occurs, because .xcdatamodel looses it's reference many times.

So to resolve this, delete the reference of your .xcdatamodel, and then add it again in your project.

Comment: Deleted (remove reference), then did File -> Add of the same.  Same compiler error.  Any other ideas?  BTW - the model is not completed, but just entities.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem after creating a new CoreData model version and immediately deleting it. The said version didn't appear in Xcode's Project Navigator but was causing the compilation error.

1. Locate the existing `.xcdatamodeld` by using show in finder.
2. Show Package Content.
3. Here is the conflicting model version, delete unwanted version and you're now sorted.

Comment: Here I had a version with zero file length that clearly wasn't in shape

Answer (score 1):

You could try to edit and re-save your data model in Xcode5.

Also, try to find out why the error mentions "Debug" in the build path when you are actually archiving. Quite possibly your project file has been updated by the Beta Xcode, so you may need to look through your target settings for anything suspicious.

In the future when using Beta software, you should always use the most up-to-date one, Beta6 as of today in this case.